# Remove unused form filters

Tags: forms, filter, doctrine

When a new schema is being created, its possible to avoid the forms filters auto-generation using the following option:

```
ExampleEntity:
  symfony:
    options:
      filters: false
```

In my particular case, the app is already in production and I would like to know the best approach to remove all unused form filters from my project. Doctrine has bundled a simple and nice task to be run or I have to delete all the files place in the filters directory?

Comment: did you find the answer for this? Trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all filters, in your `generator.yml`do:

```
...
  filter:
    class: false
...
```

If you want to remove particular ones do:

```
 ...
  filter:
    class: [filter_to_show1, filter_to_show2, filter_to_show3]  //The ones that you don't put will not be displayed 
...
```

This is Symfony 1.4.
Look at: [Symfony 1.4: how to NOT display any filter through generator.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352922/symfony-1-4-how-to-not-display-any-filter-through-generator-yml#10353311)