# Symfony 1.4: how to NOT display any filter through generator.yml

Tags: symfony-1.4, filtering

I created an admin module in **Symfony**. I would like to show the table list but **without** filters.

By default I get all filters. I managed to unset all the filters by hand -using unset, in the **filterForm file** of the module. Even more, I enabled just one filter and unset it. Used the  `unset($this->widgetSchema['filter'], ...)` for that. I don't like this solution.

I would like to do it using the `generator.yml`:

I tried:

```
  I)   filter: false

  II)  filter:
         display: false 

  III) filter:
        display: [] <-- empty!
```

None worked. I read that using credentials could be possible but I would like to do it in a more simple a concrete way.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:
My actual generator. Is the default really:

```
generator:
class: sfPropelGenerator
param:
  model_class:           halt
  theme:                 admin15
  non_verbose_templates: true
  with_show:             false
  singular:              Halt
  plural:                Halts
  route_prefix:          halt
  with_propel_route:     1
  actions_base_class:    sfActions

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    object_actions: {}
    batch_actions: {}
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

Comment: could you post your whole generator.yml ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost done but you don't test everything :)

```
filter:
  class: false
```

http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_filter

> To completely remove the filtering feature, set the class to false.